# OneDrive uploading message keeps growing

Tags: sync, onedrive, upload

I have 40GB capacity on OneDrive. Recently I updated a lot of files and folders. My main folder is now 18.5GB

OneDrive started uploading to sync the folder, but it now shows uploading 27GB of 27.4GB and both numbers keep growing and growing. The files remaining stays at about 200 and doesn't go down.

This is more than I actually have in the folder, how is this possible? And when is it finally going to sync the final 200 files?

I am using regular OneDrive linked to my school account, and Windows 10. My upload speed is 10Mb/s

Comment: Pause the sync process?

Comment: Do the files change? Is there some process working on the files?

Comment: @JustDoIt there is no pause button in onedrive. Really, the software looks like it was made yesterday in an hour by an adolescent amateur. I bet MS is thinking let's not bother people with all that techno talk and NOT show what is being uploaded. And let's not give them any control at all, since that would be difficult.

Comment: @techraf No the files don't change, I don't see the time stamps changing. Some folders are actually 'up to date', so that's not it. And still, how can it be that it shows it's uploading _more_ than there actually is in the folder??

Comment: Thats odd, my computer has an preinstalled access to my onedrive, and i can just turn it on and off at will

Comment: @JustDoIt you mean right click + exit? That's certainly not the same as pausing upload, that's stopping the whole program. Anyway I don't see an option named 'pause'.

Comment: No, I mean I can literally see the access on my directory. Ill attach a picture when I get home. What OS you're working with?

Comment: @JustDoIt I know what you mean now. The onedrive at work actually does have a pause button, and mine at home doesn't. My version at work is 6 and something and my version at home is "version 2015 Build 17.3.6302.0225". BTW I found a workaround, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a workaround, not a complete solution nor understanding of the problem.

It seems the problem is related to files that OneDrive is unable to sync, for some unknown reason.

The workaround is as follows:

1. Remove files or even complete folders that are marked as unsynced
2. Wait for OneDrive to catch up and show the files/folders as removed online
3. Upload the files and folders again using drag/drop in the browser (not the offline folder in Windows, that will just recreate the problem, I tried).